# How do I run a Visio report on many Visio diagrams at once

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I'm using Visio 2013 and I have a Visio report that I want to run on hundreds of `.vsdx` files.

How can I run the report as a batch rather than one file at a time?

Comment: Which report do you want to run? They almost all need input from the user via dialogs for each document. I think they all use the current document as their input, and nothing can change that. It's the way they are coded.

Comment: A macro won't help either, the macro recorder doesn't record the steps to run a report.

Comment: I think this question might be better stated as "Can I run a Visio report on many diagrams at once?", to which the answer would be no.